# Bash parse data from xml

Tags: xml, bash, parsing

i'm not very good at scritping so a i need a hand on this.

i have the following output that i want to parse data from:

Actual Output:

```
<connection-pool name="name1" max-connections="50" min-connections="5">
<connection-factory factory-class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" user="user1" password="xxxx" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1.domain.com:1550:name1" commit-record-table-name="">
<connection-pool name="name2" max-connections="50" min-connections="5">
<connection-factory factory-class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" user="user2" password="xxxx" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server2.domain.com:1524:name2" commit-record-table-name="">
<connection-pool name="name3" max-connections="15" min-connections="5">
<connection-factory factory-class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" user="user3" password="xxxx" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server3.domain.com:1528:name3" commit-record-table-name="">
<connection-pool name="name4" initial-limit="1" max-connections="10" min-connections="1" num-cached-statements="5">
<connection-factory factory-class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" user="user4" password="xxxx" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server4.domain.com:1538:name4" commit-record-table-name=""/>
<connection-pool name="name5" initial-limit="1" max-connections="10" min-connections="1" num-cached-statements="5">
<connection-factory factory-class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" user="user5" password="xxxx" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server5.domain.com:1537/name5"/>
```

Desired Output:

```
name="name1" max-connections="50" min-connections="5" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1.domain.com:1550:name1"
name="name2" max-connections="50" min-connections="5" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server2.domain.com:1524:name2"
name="name3" max-connections="15" min-connections="5" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server3.domain.com:1528:name3"
name="name4" max-connections="10" min-connections="1" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server4.domain.com:1538:name4"
name="name5" max-connections="10" min-connections="1" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server5.domain.com:1537/name5"
```

I would appreciate if someone could help me on this, btw it should be done in bash, since i cant install software on all production servers..

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do your production servers **really** not already ship with Python, or any other language with XML support in the standard library? Parsing XML with bash requires 3rd-party tools -- xmlstarlet, xmllint, etc.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13463365/1050015

Comment: @Carlo, given as that uses a 3rd-party tool, and the question indicates that "I can't install software on production servers"...

Comment: Use xslt for that. xsltproc from the package `limbxml2-util` will do the job

Comment: @CharlesDuffy you are right, but I thought maybe a cmd line tool was ok, it doesn't bring a whole wagon of dependecies. :)

Comment: Right if it's possible i'd like to solve this on a cmd line, because with this solution i'll make a nagios alarm and i need to keep it as simple as i could

Comment: xsltproc is fine. xmlstarlet is fine (and will actually _write_ XSLT files for you). xmllint is fine. The point is that if you care about correctness, it's mandatory to use a real parser, rather than trying to hack something together using regular expressions or such. If you're serious about the "can't install anything" constraint, and your OS ships with no such parser, your best bet might be to get that parser by way of the Python interpreter or such, even if you just make a little command-line tool you then use from your shell script.

Comment: If that's is genuinely your real input then it's not XML so you'll have to use a _text_ processing tool like `sed` or `awk` anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this isn't valid XML, might as well use sed:

```
sed -n '
  /<connection-pool /   {s///; s/\/\?>$//; s/ \(initial-limit\|num-cached-statements\)="[^"]*"//g; p} 
  /<connection-factory/ {s///; s/\/\?>$//; s/ \(factory-class\|user\|password\|commit-record-table-name\)="[^"]*"//g; p}
' connections.log | paste -d "" - -
```

```
name="name1" max-connections="50" min-connections="5" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server1.domain.com:1550:name1"
name="name2" max-connections="50" min-connections="5" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server2.domain.com:1524:name2"
name="name3" max-connections="15" min-connections="5" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server3.domain.com:1528:name3"
name="name4" max-connections="10" min-connections="1" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@server4.domain.com:1538:name4"
name="name5" max-connections="10" min-connections="1" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//server5.domain.com:1537/name5"
```